# Ruby/Rails How to Calculate and Round Prices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

Developing an invoice, I am running into math rounding issues where my unit prices and totals are not adding up perfectly.  The issue comes because of a business requirement where a hidden commission is passed down to the customer based on certain conditions. I have to go behind the scenes and multiply every price and total by the commission percentage.

For example the unrounded calculated price multiplied by a commission for example.

```
Item            Name         qty    Price2  qty2    Price   Total
Kitchen Counter Uba Tuba     100.0  72.4275 100.0   18.125  9055.249999999999   9055.249999999999
Vanity          Uba Tuba     100.0  72.4275 100.0   18.125  9055.249999999999   9055.249999999999
                                        Grand Total         18110.5
```

Now using rails number_to_currency helper applied, the numbers are off

```
Kitchen Counter Uba Tuba     100.0  $72.43  100.0   $18.13  1   $9,055.25   $9,055.25
Vanity          Uba Tuba     100.0  $72.43  100.0   $18.13  1   $9,055.25   $9,055.25
```

Due to the rounding of the prices, if a customer does their own math, the totals are off.

```
rounded total = $9056.00
```

How do you solve this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eliminate the rounding error in the line item total, you need to round the discounted unit prices to two decimals before calculating the total, i.e.

```
qty = 100.0
price = 18.125
qty2 = 100.00
price2 = 72.4275

total = qty * price.round(2) + qty2 * price2.round(2)
total.round(2) # happens in number_to_currency
#=> 9056.0
```

instead of what you're currently doing

```
total = qty * price + qty2 * price2
total.round(2) # happens in number_to_currency
#=> 9055.25
```

Comment: I like this better.  Prevents me from having to integrate a gem into a mostly complete project.

Comment: I still agree with @xlembouras that you should either use `Integer` or arbitrary precision floats (`BigDecimal`) for representing the values. Rounding problems can be hard to track down and you don't want to deal with the imprecision of normal floats as well!

Comment: Keep in mind you cannot just apply this technique if customers are expected to actually pay you the total as listed on the invoice. That is, the rounding method gives you a total of $9,056.00 but the actual price (which the customer is supposed to pay I assume) is $9,055.25.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [the money](https://github.com/Rubymoney/money) and the [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) gems will be of use!

If you want to do things manually, you should consider storing your prices as `Integer` values! Where a price of x would mean x $ cents or x tens of $ cents. By doing that you can get rid of all the rounding provblems in your db.

Also the use of [number_to_currency](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency) helper will help you display things properly to your views.

Comment: number_to_currency is what I'm using.  I'll look into the rubygems you provided

Comment: @ctilley79 the rubygems will help you for sure. The problem starts from the float representation of ruby and your database. There is no "right" way to do it with a float because `14.0` can always be `13.9999999998` for a computer. On the other hand `1400` (Int) will be just that :-)